# I can't get my recurring events identified in google calendar

Tags: icalendar

i'm using [ICAL.js](https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js) to crearte a recurring events, when I import the `.ics` file on my phone, it adds only one event!
this is the `.ics` file, what's the problem?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//Qu Studioc.//Timetable//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
FREQ:WEEKLY
BYDAY:SU,TU
SUMMARY:ESP102\n16121-training
UID:ESP1020
DTSTART:20190630T025448
DURATION:PT100M
DTSTAMP:20190704T025448
UNTIL:20200102T000000Z
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
FREQ:WEEKLY
BYDAY:SU,TU
SUMMARY:ESP102\n16121-training
UID:ESP1021
DTSTART:20190630T025448
DURATION:PT100M
DTSTAMP:20190704T025448
UNTIL:20200102T000000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An RRULE must actually be specified - the FREQ should be part of the RRULE not standalone 
The ietf.org site is not responding for me now, try 
https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html